# How can OS know my fstab?

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, fstab

I have the following `fstab` on my Raspberry PI:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    noatime,ro          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /settings       ext4    defaults,nodelalloc,noatime,commit=60 0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,nodelalloc,noatime,commit=60,ro 0       1
```

So, this data is on `/dev/mmcblk0p2` partition. How can `OS` know this prior to mounting?

Comment: The boot loader or the boot command line actually tell where to find root. But, there would of course be some case it would'nt work : Imagine fstab (in p2) is in fact a symbolic link to some fstab in p3... :-)

Comment: Also you might have an initrd.